# Error on reject of promise , react-native-vector-icons expected 1 parameter given 3

Tags: react-native, icons

[image]

When i remove any two argument it says expected three parameters given 1.
When i comment the reject status it works fine but when i run `npm update` it revert the code.

Comment: Rather than have your code in an image file, can you edit your question to put the code into it?  Also, if possible, make your question a bit more clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved in latest version.